# CssParameter stroke-width min max value Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld, line

I wonder if there is a minimum value for the stroke width parameter since I've a LineSymbolizer with stroke 0.1 but i want it to be thinner so i change the value to 0.05 but i dont see any difference on the map when the lines are drawn.

PS: sorry my english

Comment: Pedro you are right, beneath a certain width the paramter makes no difference. Probably due to the rendering. I have the same issue when using units of measure as ground metres rather than pixels.
No idea why the previous comment suggests using 0, this just means they won't draw at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css values are in pixels so you probably won't see much change with fractional values. Try using 0 as I think GeoServer handles that as a special case.

Further information on SLD can be found at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html